# Volatility is not becoming sigma in simulated GBM

Tags: volatility, geometric-brownian

I am trying to simulate GBM using values for sigma and then after calculating the price, calculate the log of returns and the associated volatility. I was expecting the calculated volatility of log returns to be equal to sigma used in the simulation, but its not the case. I would like to know if this result was expected and if so, what is wrong with my code that is preventing me from getting to the right answer.

````
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

M=1000
n=126
T=0.5
r=0.1175
sigma=0.2
S0=100
dt = T/n
np.random.seed(100)

mudt = r - 1/2*sigma**2
St=np.zeros((M,(n+1)))
St[:,0]=S0
for i in range(M):
    for j in range(n):
        St[i,j+1] = St[i,j]*np.exp(mudt*dt+sigma*np.random.normal()*dt**(0.5))

for i in range(M):
    plt.plot(St[i,:])

Ravg=np.zeros(M)
R=np.zeros((M,(n)))
for i in range(5):
    RR = pd.Series(St[i])
    RR = RR.pct_change()
    RR = np.log(RR+1)
    Ravg[i] = RR.mean()
    RR=RR.dropna()
    R[i] = RR.values
    
   
var=np.zeros(M)
for i in range(M):
    vari=0
    for j in range(n):
        vari += (R[i,j]-Ravg[i])**2
    var[i]=(vari/n)**(1/2)

```
````

Answer (score 3):

Under GBM, the log returns $\log S_{t+dt} - \log S_t$ have a standard deviation of $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{dt}}$. So you need to scale your computed standard deviation by $1/\sqrt{dt}$.

You only compute the returns for range(5), and leave the rest as zeros - So you get the wrong result.

Finally, you are using a biased estimator for the standard deviation. The divisor should be $1/(n-1)$, not $1/n$.

I have amended your code, and I get the expected result.

````
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

M=1000
n=126
T=0.5
r=0.1175
sigma=0.2
S0=100
dt = T/n
np.random.seed(100)

mudt = r - 1/2*sigma**2
St=np.zeros((M,(n+1)))
St[:,0]=S0
for i in range(M):
    for j in range(n):
        St[i,j+1] = St[i,j]*np.exp(mudt*dt+sigma*np.random.normal()*dt**(0.5))


Ravg=np.zeros(M)
R=np.zeros((M,(n)))
for i in range(M):
    RR = pd.Series(St[i])
    RR = RR.pct_change()
    RR = np.log(RR+1)
    Ravg[i] = RR.mean()
    RR=RR.dropna()
    R[i] = RR.values
    
   
var=np.zeros(M)
for i in range(M):
    vari=0
    for j in range(n):
        vari += (R[i,j]-Ravg[i])**2
    var[i]=(vari/(n-1))


std = var**0.5
np.mean(std)/(dt**0.5)
```
````